# How to assign an item in a pandas dataframe after checking for conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text-mining

I am iterating through a pandas dataframe (originally a csv file) and checking for specific keywords in each row of a certain column. If it appears at least once, I add 1 to a score. There are like 7 keywords, and if the score is >=6, I would like to assign an item of another column (but in this row) with a string (here it is "Software and application developer") and safe the score. Unfortunately, the score is everywhere the same what I find hard to believe. This is my code so far:

```
for row in data.iterrows():
devScore=0
if row[1].str.contains("developer").any() | row[1].str.contains("developpeur").any():
    devScore=devScore+1
if row[1].str.contains("symfony").any():
    devScore=devScore+1
if row[1].str.contains("javascript").any():
    devScore=devScore+1
if row[1].str.contains("java").any() | row[1].str.contains("jee").any():
    devScore=devScore+1
if row[1].str.contains("php").any():
    devScore=devScore+1
if row[1].str.contains("html").any() | row[1].str.contains("html5").any():
    devScore=devScore+1
if row[1].str.contains("application").any() | row[1].str.contains("applications").any():
    devScore=devScore+1
if devScore>=6:
    data["occupation"]="Software and application developer"
    data["score"]=devScore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a constant onto the whole column here:

```py
data["occupation"]="Software and application developer"
data["score"]=devScore
```

They are supposed to be:

```py
for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    # blah blah
    #
    .
    .
    data.loc[idx, "occupation"]="Software and application developer"
    data.loc[idx, "score"]=devScore
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this error message now:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7b416ccdaeb8> in <module>
      2 for index, row in data.iterrows():
      3     devScore=0
----> 4     if row[1].str.contains("developer").any() | row[1].str.contains("developpeur").any():
      5         devScore=devScore+1
      6     if row[1].str.contains("symfony").any():

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Can you try `row[1].contains` instead of `row[1].str.contains` ?

Comment: No, "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'"

Comment: Then change the if-statement to `if "developer" in row[1]` instead of using contains function. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just maintain a list of wanted words `goodwords` and this will perform logic you are looking for.

```
import random
import numpy as np

goodwords = ["developer","developpeur","symfony","javascript","java","jee","php","html","html5", "application","applications"]
prefix = ["a","the","junior"]
company = ["apple", "facebook", "alibaba", "grab"]

# build a dataframe where wanted text may occur in a number of columns
df = pd.DataFrame([
{col:f"{prefix[random.randint(0, len(prefix))-1]} {goodwords[random.randint(0, len(goodwords))-1] if random.randint(0,2)<=1 else 'manager'} at {company[random.randint(0, len(company))-1]}" for col in "abcdefgh"}
    for r in range(10)])

# start with a truth matrix that only contains false
matches = np.zeros(df.shape)==1
# build up trues where a goodword is in the text
for w in goodwords:
    matches = matches | df.apply(lambda r: r.str.contains(w))

# spec shows only set score column if it's >=6
# score is the sum across the row of the truth matrix (True==1)
df = (df.assign(match=matches.sum(axis=1),
         score=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["match"].ge(6), dfa["match"], np.nan),
         occupation=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["match"].ge(6), "Software and application developer", "wannabe"))
    .drop(columns="match"))
```

### output

```
                            a                              b                            c                               d                           e                           f                            g                               h  score                          occupation
             the java at grab         junior manager at grab           the html5 at apple        the applications at grab      junior manager at grab  junior application at grab       junior manager at grab  junior applications at alibaba    NaN                             wannabe
        a manager at facebook     junior application at grab       junior manager at grab          junior symfony at grab    the applications at grab   junior symfony at alibaba    junior developer at apple            a javascript at grab    6.0  Software and application developer
 junior applications at apple                  a php at grab            a manager at grab     junior applications at grab  junior manager at facebook           a php at facebook          the jee at facebook      junior javascript at apple    6.0  Software and application developer
            the html5 at grab                 a jee at apple        junior html5 at apple               a manager at grab          a manager at apple         the manager at grab   the javascript at facebook                the php at apple    NaN                             wannabe
       a applications at grab       junior developer at grab            a manager at grab          the manager at alibaba               a php at grab  junior manager at facebook          the manager at grab           a javascript at apple    NaN                             wannabe
            a manager at grab        junior manager at apple            a manager at grab       junior manager at alibaba   the javascript at alibaba        junior java at apple       a applications at grab            the manager at apple    NaN                             wannabe
          the jee at facebook              the html at apple  junior applications at grab  junior developpeur at facebook        the manager at apple      the javascript at grab           junior jee at grab       a developpeur at facebook    7.0  Software and application developer
  junior developer at alibaba        the manager at facebook                a jee at grab               a manager at grab     the manager at facebook    the applications at grab         a manager at alibaba      junior application at grab    NaN                             wannabe
         the manager at apple  junior application at alibaba  the application at facebook          junior manager at grab     junior manager at apple     junior manager at apple         the manager at apple          the symfony at alibaba    NaN                             wannabe
        junior html5 at apple    the applications at alibaba            a manager at grab          junior manager at grab    junior html5 at facebook   junior manager at alibaba  junior applications at grab        junior developer at grab    NaN                             wannabe
```